# Populate angular ui bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

How do you populate an angular ui bootstrap popover? I want to populate the popover with a list of actor names. Here is the code:

```
<div class="container" ng-if="radioModel=='Search for Actor'">
    <p>Movies played in:</p>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="name in listOfMovies">
        <td>
        <p>
          <button uib-popover="populateWithListOfData" popover-trigger="mouseenter" type="button" class="btn btn-default"> {{ name }}</button>
        </p>   
       </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

I want to be able to populate this popover for each name of the ng-repeat. So I will get a name of a movie and based on that name I want to populate the popover with a list of actors in that movie. Thanks guys.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: Where it says uib-popover="populateWithListOfData" I do not know how to populate the popover. I just put populateWithListOfData as a placeholder.

Comment: This is a good place to make a directive since in this case you've to return html based on the name of the movie.

Comment: Okay, but if I have my list of data is there a way to run a loop on the popover to populate it? I have never really created a directive because I am new to angular.

Comment: I've used something like this in the past http://plnkr.co/edit/ujp5AGHmMSCBn2ZXbc1S?p=preview . I understand you want to iterate through that data?

Comment: Yes you are correct that I want to iterate through the data. And I will take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible.
I have setup a data item called friends in JS

```
$scope.friends = [
    {name:'John'},
    {name:'Jessie'},
    {name:'Johanna'},
    {name:'Joy'}
      ];
```

Also , an array was created for the text in the popup

```
$scope.toolTip =['D','A','C','T'];
```

> **If you want to display a pop up for each row.**

I've created the ng-repeat and the relevant popover.In order to display all the letters in the first popover.

```
<div ng-repeat="f in friends">
{{f.name}}
<button  uib-tooltip="{{toolTip[$index]}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip {{placement.selected}}</button>
</div>
```

Here is a **[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/AD3sGOa8HjbUJtNA0gkI?p=preview)**

> How does it works?

Your tool tip value is set as `uib-tooltip="{{toolTip[$index]}}"`.it accesses each element according to the $index obtained from ng-repeat.

> **If you want to display all the data in the first pop up**

I've created the ng-repeat and the relevant popover.In order to display all the letters in the first popover.

```
   <div ng-repeat="f in friends">
   <div ng-if="$index==0">
   <button  uib-tooltip="{{toolTip}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Tooltip {{placement.selected}}</button>
</div>
   {{f.name}}
   </div>
```

Here is a **[working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/2LFoImNgjnujlLJZSAkn?p=preview)**

> How does it works?

Your tool tip value is set as `uib-tooltip="{{toolTip}}"`.It enters the ng-if , if the condition is met, and thus prints the array.

Comment: But see in the demo each letter is on a different popover, What I need is all the letters displayed on the first popover.

Comment: That's pretty simple too.What does your list of data look like?

Comment: @sebenalern, something like this? [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/2LFoImNgjnujlLJZSAkn?p=preview)

Comment: I removed the [$index] and it displays all the data on each popover. Accept my edit and I will accept your answer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @sebenalern, I think I lost the edit while adding a link myself

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't test if it works, but this might give you the idea.

```js
(function ()
{
    function moviePopover($compile)
    {
        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            scope: true,
            templateUrl: '<button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" popover-title="{{dynamicPopover.title}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Popover With Template</button>',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                scope.dynamicPopover = {
                    content: "Movies",
                    templateUrl: "myPopoverTemplate.html",
                    title: "Title"
                };

                if (attrs.movieName !== undefined)
                {
                    scope.movieList = getMoviesByName(attrs.movieName);
                    $compile(element)(scope);
                    //If 1st leads to infinit loop use this
                    //                    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                }

                function getMoviesByName(movieName)
                {
                    //return all moviews based on movieName
                    //here im just returning dummy array(you return your data)
                    return ["Movie1", "Movie2"];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    angular.module("myApp").directive("moviePopover", ["$compile", moviePopover]);


}());
```

```html
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myPopoverTemplate.html">
  <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="movie in movieList">{{movie}}</li>
  </ul>
</script>


<div class="container" ng-if="radioModel=='Search for Actor'">
    <p>Movies played in:</p>
      <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="name in listOfMovies">
        <td>
        <p>
          <movie-popover movie-name="{{name}}"></movie-popover>
        </p>   
       </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think this will help me in the future also.