# How to pass data from AngularJS list to Bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

At my view I have a list of items:

```
<li ng-repeat="fruit in items">
{{fruit.name}} / {{fruit.price}}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">EDIT</button>
</li>
```

And I'd like to edit each product using bootstrap modal. That's why I need to pass data of specific product to modal. After this I'll simply pass this data to angular script using `ng-click="saveFruit(dataFruit)"` and `saveFruit` will save data.

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/czus6s3a/

Comment: I think you should use [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/). It has modal directive for that purpose. [Link to modal section](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal)

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36442755/4759033) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Changed answer entirely.

Click here for a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sn8u7kqe/1/.

Changes made:

In the controller, I created a `$scope.dataFruit = null`, just to ensure the variable is initialized. I also created a function as follows:

```
$scope.setDataFruit = function(fruit) {
    $scope.dataFruit = fruit;
};
```

This was to ensure that we were assigning our fruit to the right `$scope`.

Finally, I had you move your `<div class="modal">` to **INSIDE** the `div` which had the `ng-controller` directive.

The controller will only apply it's model (variables, and functions, etc), to the elements that it has visibility of. As per your original example, the modal was OUTSIDE of the div, so the data binding would not have applied there.

Comment: Hmm, I know what you trying to do but it doesn't work for me. Can you edit my fiddle?

Comment: I've editted the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sn8u7kqe/1/. I will update my answer to reflect what I did.

Comment: I see a little problem. If I editing modal, then changes appears also on the basic view (before I clicked save)

Comment: That'll be because of the two way binding. You could use `angular.copy`, to create a copy of the `fruit`, rather than passing the actual fruit itself in the `setDataFruit`.